# No video from newly installed Radeon HD7790 graphics card on a Windows 10 PC

Tags: video, graphics-card

I have a 5 year old home theater PC (Windows 10) with a Radeon HD7790 GPU. Today I upgraded the PSU and the GPU to an AMD RX 570. I can get onboard video, but not video from the new card. I've tried all the things I've found online, and beginning to suspect a defective card.

- Windows device manager can see the card and says it is working properly
- I have installed the latest drivers from AMD. Most recently I used Wagnard DDU in Safe Mode to cleanly uninstall everything, reboot, and then install new drivers fresh.
- I have updated my motherboard UEFI
- I have replaced my CMOS battery

I have two monitors - a VGA and a DVI monitor. Both work with my onboard video. If I connect the VGA monitor and try to connect my GPU to the secondary DVI monitor, I get no output.

I can boot into windows with the GPU as the primary, and then TeamViewer in, but the TeamViewer display is only 640x480, and I don't think I can adjust the resolution. (The settings panel is below the bottom of my screen and the scrolling is somehow non-functional)

[image: Team viewer screenshot]

Comment: do you havr another pc to test the card?  also, try booting a linux live distro to see if the problem is windows?

Comment: I don't have another PC to test this. A linux boot is an interesting idea - I will look into what's involved with that.

Comment: What type of PSU do you have?  How many PCI-e power pins does the GPU have?  How many does the PSU have?  What other PCI-e devices do you have installed?  Some of these questions made involve opening the case, necessary, diagnose the problem

Comment: It's a Supernova EVGA G3. My full build is here: https://pcpartpicker.com/user/Nelluk/saved/6G7HhM

The GPU is my only PCI device. The cable running from the GPU to the PSU is 8 pins on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Often there will be a setting in BIOS that selects the graphics adapter to use.

I'm not as familiar with this in modern UEFI bios's but it certainly used to be the case that you would have to go into BIOS and select to use your external GPU rather than the onboard one.

Comment: My BIO has an option for default display - onboard or PCI card. I can only boot into windows (visibly) if I select onboard or if the GPU is physically disconnected. If I connect card and select PCI setting, I get no video.

Comment: Doesn't sound good for the GPU then I'm afraid, short of swapping in a different GPU or trying this one in a different computer I don't think there is much else you can do.

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS' UEFI Setup Utility under **[Advanced\Chipset Configuration](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/H81M-ITX.pdf)** make sure **IGPU Multi-Monitor** is set to **Enabled**, this allows the the integrated graphics to work when an external graphics card is installed.

Comment: I just enabled this in my last round of troubleshooting (replacing the CMOS battery). It did not make a difference. At this point I am 99% convinced of defective GPU.

Comment: And you are sure you have the **Primary Graphics Adapter** set to **PCI Express** and have you updated the [Radeon graphics drivers to version 18.9.3](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-570)?

Comment: Yes. Primary Graphics Adapter has been the main setting I've been messing with as I *only* get video when its set to Onboard.
I installed Radeon drivers 18.12.1